# I cannot find the service in IBM cloud that I am looking for, but I know it is there

Tags: ibm-cloud

I was on this webpage and decided I wanted to sign up for Watson's Text Analytics service.
https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/natural-language-understanding/self-service/home

However, after 20 minutes of searching I am unable to find anything like this in the IBM cloud.  I followed the link on the same page to sign up.

Can someone please tell me the name of the service that is displayed in the Natural-Language-Understanding webpage so that I can learn more about it and sign up for it?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The link is https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding
Generally, you can access IBM Cloud and search any service from the Catalog section